# How can I measure the resistance of non-linear devices using a digital multimeter?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistance, multimeter, ohms-law

Is the value of resistance that appears when we measure the resistance using a DMM at the terminals of any electronic device the total equivalent resistance of that device which is also called load resistance in electronic circuits?

How do DMMs measure it? The devices contain non-linear components. For linear circuits we have Thevenin and Norton theorems and almost every electronic device is a non-linear device because it contains non-linear components and there is no theorem for non linear devices. Are the resistance values wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the multimeter shows as resistance is based on what the multimeter has measured as the circuit voltage with the current it provides to test the circuit.

So only assuming that the load is a linear load resistance to begin with, you can take voltage and current in a circuit and divide voltage by current and show the result in ohms.

But if the load is not a resistance, but e.g a diode, of course you still get some measured current and voltage, but the result is resistance but the load is not resistance so it just the value of equivalent resistance the multimeter has calculated from the voltage and current.

So yes, in the sense, what the multimeter shows you is the resistance based on current, but only at the current the multimeter outputs, if the test current is different then the voltage will be different and for a non-linear load the relation of current and voltage is not linear so shown resistance will change as well.

So you get different resistances depending on the current injected by the multimeter, and the resistances measured have no relation to current or voltage at some other voltage or current.

Comment: So you are saying that the non linear circuits containing active elements and reactive components, the resistance measured using the multimeter value is wrong so that value cant be used ?

Comment: What i think is that because it is a non linear circuit with reactive components the circuit's impedance should be measured instead of resistance using DMM so there should be another device that we should use for impedance. what's your thoughts are on this?

Comment: @Ahsan Multimeters measure resistance with the assumption that the probed thing is a resistance. The measured resistance value is not correct if the probed thing is not a resistance. You can use a RLC meter to measure caps and inductors, but it does not again measure active components like diodes or ICs.

Comment: Ok so the readings are definitely wrong then because the device i was measuring have active and reactive components as well other than resistive components.

Comment: And can you kindly tell me how can i find the impedance of a non linear device with reactive component like any device that can find the complete equivalent impedance of the device ?

Answer (score 1):

A non-linear resistor can be thought as a *dynamic* (self-varying) resistor that changes its present ("static") resistance when the current through or the voltage across it changes. For example, when we increase the current through a diode, it decreases its static resistance, and the product of the two quantities (the voltage) remains almost unchanged - V = I.R.  Conversely, when we increase the voltage across the collector-emitter junction of a transistor, it increases its static resistance and the ratio of the two quantities (the current) remains almost unchanged - I = V/R.

So when you connect an ohmmeter to a non-linear element, it reads its static resistance. If you switch the range of the ohmmeter (or replace it with another one), the current and, accordingly, the resistance reading will change.

Comment: For a single non linear element but i am asking about a non-linear circuit or a device that contains non linear elements and reactive components. If we measure the resistance at the terminals of those circuits we get resistance so i was asking whether that value is correct and how a non linear device impedance is measured by the DMM

Comment: @Ahsan, A DC multimeter (acting as an ohmmeter) will simply pass a reference current through your circuit and will measure the voltage drop across it. After some time, reactive elements will not affect the reading that will be R = V/I (aka "static resistance" of the circuit).

Comment: so it means that multimeter cant measure the resistance of non linear circuits then.

Comment: @Ahsan, It will measure the *static* (*constant*, *ohmic*, *DC*) resistance but it can't measure the *differential resistance* and *impedance* of the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

A DMM is buiilt around a volt meter  often reading +/- 200mV  and then scaling the result for display.

For measuring resistance on the 200 ohms range it applies a imA current through the test leads and reports the voltage it sees in response.
on the 2K ohms range it applies 0.1mA and activates a decimal point on the display etc...

Answer (score 0):

Others explained how a dmm ohm meter works and why it probably won’t work for you.

You can still use a DMM to measure non-linear R however if you provide your own source. Measure I, measure V and calculate ohms at whatever operating point you want.

(In general ohm meters are useful but limiting.  For example if I’m measuring a relay or a shunt I pump amps through it and measure a reasonable V).

Comment: Well the non linear device contains non linear elements and reactive components, if i am using the DMM to measure the resistance and it was giving a value is that value correct because non linear devices impedance should be measured instead of resistance and if the measured value is correct then how it did it i don't understand this.

Answer (score 0):

If voltage is a nonlinear function of current, then resistance will also be a function of current, and the best you can measure is a curve of voltage vs current over some range of voltage and current.  Wikipedia has this great figure:

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current%E2%80%93voltage_characteristic

For a linear device like the resistors, the slope of the line is linear and has a single value, the resistance.  For the nonlinear device like the diode, the slope changes, so at each point along the curve you can measure a value, but there is no one single resistance.  It changes depending on the voltage. When you put your DMM on the diode, it applies some voltage or current, and measures the slope at that voltage/current.

As for your other questions in the comments, reactance is also a linear property, so you can measure it normally with a DMM if the system is linear.  If you try and measure it on a nonlinear device, you will have the same problem that it depends on where you measure it on the curve.

Comment: With multimeter i think measuring reactance would be difficult as well because multimeter will pass a dc current and the reactive component after a small time will stop behaving and for single non-linear components you are correct but i was asking for a resistance measurement of a complete non linear device.

Comment: @Ahsan Reactance is measured by applying a time varying signal not DC.  Why do you think the above wouldn't apply to a "complete" nonlinear device?  The DMM has no way to know if something is nonlinear because it is 1 diode or 1000 diodes.

Comment: But the behavior will cause the reading to go wrong like you mentioned reactance is a frequency dependent quantity. When DMM applies a small dc current inductor behaves as short circuit and capacitor will act as open after charging so that current will take alternate routes or use planes in PCB to return so we will have some charged components and reactance can't be measured in linear circuits using DMM also non linear device work operating points and work on frequency inputs so behavior will tell DMM. That's the conclusion i came up with that DMM cannot measure non linear device.

Comment: @Ahsan It is no problem for a DMM to measure reactance.  That is what the capacitance setting does.